# Identify group of records after another group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to identify groups of records that come after other groups. We have members who left one group and came back but should not have been put back into another subgroup.

I am trying to identify months when the member returned - after the initial enrollment. I have tried to group them in various ways (Row_Num, Rank, GROUPing) but haven't figured it out.

I want to identify the highlighted months where a member becomes eligible after becoming ineligible. To make it more challenging, some members start as ineligible (0, 1, 0, 1). I want to identify the second and subsequent groups where **Enrolled = 1** by months - possibly by adding an additional column to group the changes like the column in BLUE below.

[image]

Here's some sample data. Any other suggestions as to how to make this work would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(MEMBER VARCHAR(20), MDATE DATE, ELIGIBLE INT, ENROLLED INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP ( MEMBER, MDATE, ELIGIBLE, ENROLLED )
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-04-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-05-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-06-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-07-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-08-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-09-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-10-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-11-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2017-12-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-04-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-05-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-06-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-07-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-08-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-09-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-10-01' AS MDATE, 0 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-11-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2018-12-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2019-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2019-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'JUDY' AS MEMBER, '2019-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-04-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-05-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-06-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-07-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-08-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-09-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-10-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-11-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2017-12-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-04-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-05-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-06-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-07-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-08-01' AS MDATE, 0 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-09-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-10-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-11-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2018-12-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2019-01-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2019-02-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 1 AS ENROLLED UNION  
SELECT 'FRANK' AS MEMBER, '2019-03-01' AS MDATE, 1 AS ELIGIBLE, 0 AS ENROLLED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "some members start as ineligible (0, 1, 0, 1)", but based on your desired output:

```
WITH TEMP2(MEMBER, MDATE, ELIGIBLE, ENROLLED, CHANGED) AS (
    SELECT MEMBER, MDATE, ELIGIBLE, ENROLLED,CASE WHEN ELIGIBLE=(LAG(ELIGIBLE) OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER ORDER BY MEMBER, MDATE)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CHANGED
    FROM #TEMP
)
SELECT  MEMBER, MDATE, ELIGIBLE, ENROLLED, SUM(CHANGED) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY MEMBER, MDATE) QUESTIONMARK
FROM TEMP2
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it will work for me. I was vague about it but I did need to group by member but I just added that as the first field in the PARTITION BY to do it. I don't understand the `PARTITION BY 1` though - I would guess that the 1 refers to the first column but evidently not.

Comment: `PARTITION BY 1` means: put the constant value 1 to all the records when building the partitions (= all the records are in the same set). `PARTITION BY ...` is optional in SQL standard so I suggest you simply remove that to avoid being misled. It has no effects in that case.

Comment: @FXD - thanks, I understand now. I actually use Member in that Partition since I need the count to start over for each member.